# Cant veryfi data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table `ver_code` in my database and inside the table there is only one row called `code` and i have inserted few verification code like ABCDEF , GHIJKL for instance now my following code has failed to verify code from my table using a simple form below

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['ver_code']))
    {

        $ver_code = $_POST['ver_code'];

        if(!empty($ver_code)){

            try{
                $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pro1", "pro1", "4931//4931");
            }
            catch(PDOException $pe)
                {
                    die('Connection error, because: ' .$pe->getMessage());
                }

                $sql = "SELECT `code` FROM `ver_code`";
                $stmt = $conn->query($sql);

                if(!$stmt)
                {
                    die("Execute query error, because: ". $conn->errorInfo());
                }

                $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $row = $stmt->fetch();

                if($row['code'] == $ver_code['code']){

                    echo "Account Verified ! ";

                }else{
                    echo "Invalid Verification Code !";
                }



        }else{
         echo "Plz enter a verification code ... ";
        }

    }

?>

<form action="index2.php" method="POST" >
    <input type="text" name="ver_code" />
    <input type="submit" value="Verify" />
</form>
```

Comment: however when i turn  $row['code'] == $ver_code['code'] into  $row['code'] == $_POST['ver_code'])  then it can only verify one data from row ( only ABCDEF )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i doubt this line

`$row['code'] == $ver_code['code']`

it should be

`$row['code'] == $ver_code;` as `$ver_code` is simple `post` variable not an array.

EDIT: if you need to verify from all rows

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `code` FROM `ver_code` where code= ?"); 
$stmt->bindParam(1,$ver_code);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->rowCount()>0){
echo "Account Verified ";
}else{ echo "Invalid Verification Code";}
```

Comment: if you need to verify data from all rows why don't you user `SELECT code FROM `ver_code where code=$ver_code`

Comment: Well that solves my problem ... thank you very much ... and here is the full code ...